# Page loaded over HTTPS but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint

Tags: javascript, http, ssl, https, xmlhttprequest

I have a page with some D3 javascript on. This page sits within a HTTPS website, but the certificate is self-signed.

When I load the page, my D3 visualisations do not show, and I get the error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://integration.jsite.com/data/vis' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://integration.jsite.com/data/rdata.csv'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I did some research and all I found what the JavaScript will make the call with the same protocol that the page was loaded. So if page was loaded via `https` then the **rdata.csv** should also have been requested via `https`, instead it is requested as `http`.

Is this because the certificate is self-signed on the server? What I can do to fix this, other than installing a real SSL certificate?

Comment: Maybe [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) would help (for free and real SSL certs, check out [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)...)

Comment: it simply means the website works on https and you made a request through http, which gets rejected. you need to make your request to https by updating your request url.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> What I can do to fix this (other than installing a real SSL certificate).

**You can't.**

On an https webpage you can only make AJAX request to https webpage (With a certificate trusted by the browser, if you use a self-signed one, it will not work for your visitors)

Comment: I moved the code to an environment where proper `HTTPS` is in place, but still have the same issue!

Comment: If the data you request is not in the same domain, the domain providing the data must allow it with CORS or JSONP. What does your browser console says now?

Comment: It says the exact same thing, and it is sitting within the same domain. By the way, what I mean by proper `https` is that it is now green, and browser says `This page is secure (valid HTTPS)` Where as before the `https` was red and the browser said `This page is insecure (broken HTTPS)`.

Comment: In your JS code, for the AJAX request, do you specify https for the url?

Comment: No, I use a relative path, for example `../data/rdata.csv`

Comment: In the network console, do you see that request? Is it https (it should because your main page is https and you use relative path)? Are you sure that request doesn't redirect to http?

Comment: Can we except one URL or domain using htaccess?

Answer (score 42):

**Steps to Allow Insecure Content in Chrome**
To allow insecure content on individual sites within `Chrome`, click on the lock icon in the URL bar, then click 'Site settings'.

[image]

There you will see a list of various permissions the page has. Choose 'Allow' next to 'Insecure content'.

[image]

Now your `HTTPS` site can access `HTTP` endpoint

Comment: For some dev environments this is a good workaround to the issue

Comment: This is a good workaround for my test case, cheers!

Comment: This is good for development purpose!

Answer (score 22):

I had the same issue with my angular project. Then, I made it work in Chrome by changing the settings.

Go to Chrome setting --> Site setting --> Insecure content --> click add button of allow, then add your domain name
`[*.]XXXX.biz`

Now the problem will be solved.

Comment: is there any option for mobile browsers ? Web browsers are working

Answer (score 22):

You will be able to solve the error by adding this code to your **html** file:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests" />
```

If any solutions don't work, try this solution.

Comment: also worked for me! Adding a slash to the requesting url didn't work...

Answer (score 14):

I solved the problem by adding a slash at the end of the requested URL.

This way ✅:

```bash
/data/180/
```

Instead of ❌:

```bash
/data/180
```

Comment: This solved my problem too. Why? I don't know.

Comment: Me too, it worked. Thumbs up.

Comment: This worked for me too... Sometime to do with / being a completely separate endpoint than the non-slash variant? Can someone explain?

Comment: same here, I don't even need to add the meta element

Comment: In my case I actually had to remove the slash at the end... Not sure why tough.

Answer (score 3):

As for me, I had same warning.

I fixed it at URL request.
I had excessive '/'.

Before:
const url = `${URL}search/movie/?api_key=${API_KEY}&query=${movie}`;

After:
const url = `${URL}search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&query=${movie}`;

Answer (score 1):

Add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">` to the html file, this would solve the issue.

You can read more on [Mozilla Develop Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but from IIS in visual studio, I went to project properties -> Web -> and project url change http to https

Comment: thank you, changing my base url from http to https helped me

Answer (score 0):

One solution here server side end point which you access via https, which then makes the call to whichever http url, and then and returns the result. In other words, making your own little HTTPS proxy to access the http resource

Answer (score 0):

```
update core_config_data 
set value='X-Forwarded-Proto' 
where path='web/secure/offloader_header'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -16):

this is easy,
if you use .htaccess , check http: for https: ,
if you use codeigniter, check config : url_base -> you url http change for https.....
I solved my problem.

Comment: You should really elaborate your answer so that it's useful for others. What "check http: for https:" means?

Comment: Please provide more detail on how this fixes the problem