# GitHub Pages gives 404 error when tries to load an HTTP resource

Tags: http, github, https, github-pages

As the title says, when I try to load an HTTPS (not HTTP**S**) resource from a web host, GitHub Pages always gives me the 404 when tries to execute the GET method.

In example. having this piece of code:

```
<video width="560" controls="">
  <source src="http://webhost.com/data/aaa/aaa.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Always returns: `GET https://webhost.com/data/aaa/aaa.mp4 404` (note that is `https` and not `http`).

There is a way to bypass the enforced HTTPS?

Comment: I don't think github pages automatically rewrites http to https. It's more likely your browser is doing that.

Comment: @Evert you were right, Chrome does that automatically, to "solve" this I used https://stackoverflow.com/a/69359943/19096896